# how to handle location pop up in Android device

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, cucumber

When the app under test gets launched for the first time, it displays a Location permission popup. For that I used .setCapability("autoAcceptAlerts", true); but it not working also I tried perfectoOptions.put("perfecto:alertText", "Allow"); this also not worked.

I used **.setCapability("autoAcceptAlerts", true);** but it not working also I tried **perfectoOptions.put("perfecto:alertText", "Allow");** this also not worked.